# Running sh script from php inside screen

Tags: php, bash, phantomjs, sh, gnu-screen

That one is a strange one and i'm not sure where to look for answers.

I have a `scriptname.sh` script which i manually run from a manually launched screen session. This scriptname.sh invokes a separate PHP script, which in turn executes a command like that:

`$proc = popen("su username -c 'timeout 120 phantomjs --proxy=".$ip.":".$port." --cookies-file=/some/path/cookies/".$filename." /some/path/bot.js \"".$firstParam."\" \"".$secParam."\" '", 'r');`

Everything is fine and runs smoothly in the example above.

However, i wanted to automate this process (cron) and free myself from having to execute everything manually when server reboots.

Here comes the problem. When i execute the script via screen command, like this:

`screen -dmS screenname /path/to/scriptname.sh`

variables `$ip` and `$port` are not being passed to the command line. Weirdly `$filename`, `$firstParam` and `$secParam` pass just fine. The actual scriptname.sh executes and does run inside the created screen, but without the mentioned PHP variables. They are lost somewhere in the process. **So `ps aux` gives this output:**

`sh -c su www-data -c 'timeout 120 phantomjs --proxy=: --cookies-file=/some/path/cookies/cookiename.txt /some/path/bot.js "firstparam" "secondparam"`

`su www-data -c timeout 120 phantomjs --proxy=: --cookies-file=/some/path/cookies/cookiename.txt /some/path/bot.js "firstparam" "secondparam"`

`sh -c timeout 120 phantomjs --proxy=: --cookies-file=/some/path/cookies/cookiename.txt /some/path/bot.js "firstparam" "secondparam"`

`timeout 120 phantomjs --proxy=: --cookies-file=/some/path/cookies/cookiename.txt /some/path/bot.js firstparam secondparam`

`phantomjs --proxy=: --cookies-file=/some/path/cookies/cookiename.txt /some/path/bot.js firstparam secondparam`

**instead of this:**

`sh -c su www-data -c 'timeout 120 phantomjs --proxy=117.164.2.159:8123 --cookies-file=/some/path/cookiename.txt /some/path/bot.js "http://firstparam.is.url" "http://secparam.is.url.too" '`

`su www-data -c timeout 120 phantomjs --proxy=117.164.2.159:8123 --cookies-file=/some/path/cookiename.txt /some/path/bot.js "http://firstparam.is.url" "http://secparam.is.url.too"`

`sh -c timeout 120 phantomjs --proxy=117.164.2.159:8123 --cookies-file=/some/path/cookiename.txt /some/path/bot.js "http://firstparam.is.url" "http://secparam.is.url.too"`

`timeout 120 phantomjs --proxy=117.164.2.159:8123 --cookies-file=/some/path/cookiename.txt /some/path/bot.js http://firstparam.is.url http://secparam.is.url.too`

`phantomjs --proxy=117.164.2.159:8123 --cookies-file=/some/path/cookiename.txt /some/path/bot.js http://firstparam.is.url http://secparam.is.url.too`

The question is - **why and how to fix that?** Any help would be greatly appreciated. Am i escaping characters in a wrong way...? Also, any optimization tips are more than welcome.

Comment: Have you echoed the `$ip` and `$port` variables in the PHP script to make sure they are set immediately before the `popen()`?

Comment: Yes, you can see `--proxy=:` as opposed to `--proxy=117.164.2.159:8123`. Same PHP script.

Comment: Yes, I see, but that is the `ps -aux` output of the `popen()` call if I understand it correctly. But how do you know `$ip` and `$port` are set in the PHP program immediately _before_ that `popen()` call?

Comment: `ps -aux` is called outside of the screen.

`$proxyParts = explode(":", $eliteArray[array_rand($eliteArray)]);
$ip = $proxyParts[0];
$port = $proxyParts[1];
echo "Using " . $ip . ":" . $port . " \n";
$filename = trim(chr(mt_rand(32,32)).substr(md5(time()),1)) . ".txt";

while (@ ob_end_flush());
echo $cmd = ("su username -c 'timeout 120 phantomjs --proxy=".$ip.":".$port." --cookies-file=/some/path/cookies/".$filename." /some/path/bot.js \"".$firstparam."\" \"".$secondparam."\" '");
$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
`

Comment: `$ip` and `$port` declarations are a few lines above `popen`.

Comment: I see. And can you see the output of that `echo` statement (`"Using " . $ip`...) somewhere?

Comment: You can add 'tee /tmp/somewhere' after your echo statement. You can also look at `set -v` and `set -x` for more command feedback.